# Cloning a linux installation to multiboot with the original

Tags: multi-boot, uefi, arch-linux, bootloader, disk-cloning

I installed arch linux on an empty drive partitioned as gpt on an UEFI board.

My plan is to have three copies of this insatllation for the reasons that i'll furtherr detail.

the partition table actrually looks lie this:

```
/dev/sda1    FAT32    EFI/BOOT 500MB
/dev/sda2    swap     swap 32 GB
/dev/sda3    ext4     emergency  2GB
/dev/sda4    ext4     arch_linux 450 GB
/dev/sda5    ext4     backup
```

So as you probably can deduce from that table I plan to have sda3 as an emergency (minimal) install, sda4 as the actual os and sda5 as a backup.

I already have installed the emergency os on sda3 and succesfully booted into it, but i'm unable to boot on sda4 which was populated by:

```
    cp -rav mnt/sda3/* mnt/sda4
```

I also run grub-mkconfig on sda3 but it hasn't detected the copied linux.

Obviously I could follow all the process of intallation in all three partitions, but it's a waaste of time.

What I'm doung wrong and how is it supposed to be done?

Comment: Often you can install faster than trying to resolve all the issues. You cannot have duplicate UUIDs & GUIDs, so would have to change all those & find all places used in system & change them. At minimum reinstall grub & edit fstab. Just do a new install & restore from your normal backup. That should include /home, list of installed apps and maybe any server type apps that have data in / folders.  I use Ubuntu & new install to SSD is about 10 minutes. I copy /home which is tiny, but have data partition that I just need to mount & use a script for that. Longest time is reinstalling apps.

Comment: Just as a side note, 32 GB of swap seems _very_ overkill for most situations. (Except for hibernation, but with such amounts of RAM it'll just be slow.)

Comment: Can you clarify whether `sda1` is planned to be mounted at /boot or at /boot/efi or at /efi?

Comment: @user sda1 is an efi partition for gpt /boot is loicated on sda3 and sda4 respectively

Comment: @oldfred may be the solution is using ubuntu instead of arch.

Comment: @oldfred may be the solution is using ubuntu instead of arch. for your comment I could guess that you never installed arch linux and you knowhow complex and long the installation process is. To be fair it's not rocket science but it's a delicate and most of all long process. Even in ubuntu you have to configure sudo set up user accounts, hostnames, locales, grub, etc, It's very comprensible that I'm trying to avoid all that on the long time.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all I needed was to install os-prober, and enable it in /etc/grub/grub.conf, by adding GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROB=false

then run grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg on any system and it will detect and add entries for the others.

This problem was already solved before asking here but I was unable to see that, because always remember to change the host name in hostname or at least thouroughly check where is root mounted, if you dont you wont be able to diferentiate the login prompts